# Merging and reordering two arrays of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, javascript-objects

I'm trying to figure out how to merge two arrays of objects. Here's what I need to do:

- `field` property is the unique identifier of each object
- Output needs to only have the objects listed in the `originalArray`
- Order of `localStorageArray` needs to be maintained, with attention paid to previous requirement (order should be: `bar`, `foo`, `baz`)
- Output needs to contain the following property values from `localStorageArray`: `hidden` and `width` (`field` is a give-in, since its the identifier)
- All other properties of `originalArray` need to be maintained in output

Here's my wack at it:

```
outputArray.forEach(function(originalItem){
    localStorageArray.forEach(function(localItem){
        if(originalItem.field === localItem.field){
            originalItem.hidden = localItem.hidden;
            originalItem.width = localItem.width;
        }
    });
});
```

## [Full JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fmpeyton/sufr5wop/)

I was able to get the properties all right, but I'm a little lost on how to reorder according to `localStorageArray`. I first thought to do so within the previous set of `.forEach()` functions, but then I thought not to mess with the order within the `forEach` loops, since I thought that might mess some things up.

Any suggestions to my solution?

Here are my arrays:

```
var originalArray = [{
        field: "foo",
        hidden: true,
        sortable: false,
        template: "<div>#=text#</div>",
        width: "20px",
        propA: "a",
        propB: "b"
    }, {
        field: "bar",
        hidden: false,
        sortable: false,
        template: "",
        width: "20%",
        propC: "C"
    }, {
        field: "baz",
        hidden: false,
        sortable: true,
        template: "<span>#=text#</span>",
        int: 3
    }];

var localStorageArray = [{
        field: "bar",
        hidden: false,
        sortable: false,
        width: "100px"
    }, {
        field: "foo",
        hidden: true,
        sortable: false,
        template: "<div>#=text#</div>",
        width: "40px"
    }, {
        field: "boo",
        hidden: true,
        sortable: true,
        template: "<div>Boo: #=text#</div>",
        width: "200px"
    }, {
        field: "baz",
        hidden: true,
        template: "baz:#=text#",
        width: "20px"
    }];
```

And here is my desired output:

```
var desiredArray = [{
        field: "bar",
        hidden: false,
        sortable: false,
        template: "",
        width: "100px",
        propC: "C"
    }, {
        field: "foo",
        hidden: true,
        sortable: false,
        template: "<div>#=text#</div>",
        width: "40px",
        propA: "a",
        propB: "b"
    }, {
        field: "baz",
        hidden: true,
        sortable: true,
        template: "<span>#=text#</span>",
        width: "20px",
        int: 3
    }];
```

Comment: Can you give some sample input data and the expected output?

Comment: You say that `All other properties of originalArray need to be maintained in output` but in you fiddle the `desiredArray` contains `{field: "foo", hidden: true, sortable: false, template: "<div>#=text#</div>", width: "40px", propA: "a", propB: "b"},` and `originalArray` has the value of `width: "20px"`?

Comment: @Xotic750 - As my requirements said,  I wanted to keep `hidden` and `width` from `localStorageArray`. `width: "40px"` is from `localStorageArray` so my output is indeed correct.

Comment: Because the day is keyed, have you considered using an object hash rather than array?

Comment: @martypdx I haven't, but I do not have control over the structure of these objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example using ES6 methods.

```js
/*global document, console, expect */
(function () {
    'use strict';

    var originalArray = [{
            field: 'foo',
            hidden: true,
            sortable: false,
            template: '<div>#=text#</div>',
            width: '20px',
            propA: 'a',
            propB: 'b'
        }, {
            field: 'bar',
            hidden: false,
            sortable: false,
            template: '',
            width: '20%',
            propC: 'C'
        }, {
            field: 'baz',
            hidden: false,
            sortable: true,
            template: '<span>#=text#</span>',
            int: 3
        }],
        localStorageArray = [{
            field: 'bar',
            hidden: false,
            sortable: false,
            width: '100px'
        }, {
            field: 'foo',
            hidden: true,
            sortable: false,
            template: '<div>#=text#</div>',
            width: '40px'
        }, {
            field: 'boo',
            hidden: true,
            sortable: true,
            template: '<div>Boo: #=text#</div>',
            width: '200px'
        }, {
            field: 'baz',
            hidden: true,
            template: 'baz:#=text#',
            width: '20px'
        }],
        desiredArray = [{
            field: 'bar',
            hidden: false,
            sortable: false,
            template: '',
            width: '100px',
            propC: 'C'
        }, {
            field: 'foo',
            hidden: true,
            sortable: false,
            template: '<div>#=text#</div>',
            width: '40px',
            propA: 'a',
            propB: 'b'
        }, {
            field: 'baz',
            hidden: true,
            sortable: true,
            template: '<span>#=text#</span>',
            width: '20px',
            int: 3
        }],
        outputArray = [],
        pre = document.getElementById('out'),
        equalField = function (originalElement) {
            return originalElement.field === this.field;
        };

    localStorageArray.reduce(function (acc, localElement) {
        var original = originalArray.find(equalField, localElement),
            shallowCopy;

        if (original) {
            shallowCopy = Object.assign({}, original);
            shallowCopy.hidden = localElement.hidden;
            shallowCopy.width = localElement.width;
            acc.push(shallowCopy);
        }

        return acc;
    }, outputArray);

    try {
        expect(outputArray).to.eql(desiredArray);
        pre.textContent = 'outputArray is equal to desiredArray\n\n';
    } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
        pre.textContent = 'outputArray is not equal to desiredArray\n\n';
    }

    pre.textContent += JSON.stringify(outputArray, null, 2);
}());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/es6-shim/0.32.0/es6-shim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/expect.js/0.2.0/expect.min.js"></script>
<pre id="out"></pre>
```

UPDATE: Based on your new comment and data, then this may be a solution.

```js
var originalArray = [{
        field: "foo",
        hidden: true,
        sortable: false,
        template: "<div>#=text#</div>",
        width: "20px",
        propA: "a",
        propB: "b"
    }, {
        field: "bee",
        hidden: true,
        sortable: false,
        template: "=#text#",
        int: 4
    }, {
        field: "bar",
        hidden: false,
        sortable: false,
        template: "",
        width: "20%",
        propC: "C"
    }, {
        field: "baz",
        hidden: false,
        sortable: true,
        template: "<span>#=text#</span>",
        int: 3
    }],
    localStorageArray = [{
        field: "bar",
        hidden: false,
        sortable: false,
        width: "100px"
    }, {
        field: "foo",
        hidden: true,
        sortable: false,
        template: "<div>#=text#</div>",
        width: "40px"
    }, {
        field: "boo",
        hidden: true,
        sortable: true,
        template: "<div>Boo: #=text#</div>",
        width: "200px"
    }, {
        field: "baz",
        hidden: true,
        template: "baz:#=text#",
        width: "20px"
    }],
    desiredArray = [{
        field: "bar",
        hidden: false,
        sortable: false,
        template: "",
        width: "100px",
        propC: "C"
    }, {
        field: "bee",
        hidden: true,
        sortable: false,
        template: "=#text#",
        int: 4
    }, {
        field: "foo",
        hidden: true,
        sortable: false,
        template: "<div>#=text#</div>",
        width: "40px",
        propA: "a",
        propB: "b"
    }, {
        field: "baz",
        hidden: true,
        sortable: true,
        template: "<span>#=text#</span>",
        width: "20px",
        int: 3
    }],
    outputArray = [],
    pre = document.getElementById('out'),
    equalField = function (originalElement) {
        return originalElement.field === this.field;
    };

localStorageArray.reduce(function (acc, localElement) {
    var original = originalArray.find(equalField, localElement),
        shallowCopy;

    if (original) {
        shallowCopy = Object.assign({}, original);
        shallowCopy.hidden = localElement.hidden;
        shallowCopy.width = localElement.width;
        acc.push(shallowCopy);
    }

    return acc;
}, outputArray);

originalArray.forEach(function (originalElement, index) {
    if (!this.find(equalField, originalElement)) {
        this.splice(index, 0, Object.assign({}, originalElement));
    }
}, outputArray);

try {
    expect(outputArray).to.eql(desiredArray);
    pre.textContent = 'outputArray is equal to desiredArray\n\n';
} catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
    pre.textContent = 'outputArray is not equal to desiredArray\n\n';
}

pre.textContent += JSON.stringify(outputArray, null, 2);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/es6-shim/0.32.0/es6-shim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/expect.js/0.2.0/expect.min.js"></script>
<pre id="out"></pre>
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, but it doesn't keep all of my requirements, specifically retaining the `hidden` and `width` values from `localStorageArray`. @Jyoti Puri has a very simple and effective solution.

Answer (score 1):

Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/j2u2hhk6/

You can actually do it like this:

```
var outputArray = [];

localStorageArray.forEach(function(localItem){
    originalArray.forEach(function(originalItem){
        if(originalItem.field === localItem.field){
            var item = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(originalItem));
            item.hidden = localItem.hidden;
            item.width = localItem.width;
            outputArray.push(item);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: That is genius and so simple! I'll double check again when I'm at my computer. Thanks!

Comment: Be aware this is an O(n^2) and may perform poorly if your array sizes grow large. In that case you would want to sort the arrays first or use some combination of a hash to track the keys.

Comment: Some efficiency can be gained by merely changing the second `forEach` for `some` and returning `true` if matched.

Comment: I did find one issue with the solution, though I didn't mention it in my question: When I have an object in the `originalArray` that doesn't exist in the `outputArray`, the new object isn't included in the `newArray`. Any ideas?: http://jsfiddle.net/fmpeyton/4k6djpum/

Comment: A game changing comment.

Comment: Yep, that problem will be there. But since you mentioned that you want to have items in order as in localStorageArray, that made me think that you do not want items of originalArray that are not present in localStorageArray. If you want all elements of originalArray in outputArray, what order would you prefer for items - that will help me design the algo.

Comment: Check this updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/j2u2hhk6/1/ . It will append new items in originalArray towards the end of output array.